# Can't import helper functions from module - "cannot import name ..." error

Tags: python, import, dependencies

I have two scripts, a main file and a smaller module storing some helper functions. My main script opens with

```
from collections import namedtuple

import rospy
import serial
from sensor_msgs.msg import Imu, MagneticField

from quaternions import euler_deg2rad, euler2quat_ZYX
```

and in quaternions.py, I have

```
from collections import namedtuple
import numpy as np

def euler_deg2rad(yaw, pitch, roll):
   ....
```

Attempting to run the main script throws an `ImportError: cannot import name 'euler_deg2rad' from 'quaternions'`

What's going on here? Is importing namedtuple twice creating a circular dependency? Replacing the 'from' import in the main file with just `import quaternions` works fine, but I'd rather not import the whole module.

Comment: what's your directory structure? are these all just files next to each other in the same directory?

Comment: Yeah, they're both in the same directory. It's throwing me that a full import works but a "from" import fails.

Comment: try a couple things: `import quaternions; print(quaternions.__file)` make sure that matches the expected location. Also, try, `import quaternions; print(quaternions. euler_deg2rad)` make sure that your expected function actually exists in there. or, maybe, `import quaternions; print(dir(quaternions))`. I'm suspecting your importing a different `quaternions` module/library, but, hard to know

Comment: I ended up solving it by moving the relevant quaternion functions directly into the main file. Turns out the root of the problem was some weirdness with how ROS calls files and handles imports, and since I only needed two functions just putting them in the main file was easier than navigating ROS properly.